# GridView grid delegate display grids the same on all devices

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I used gridView.builder. To set the size of the grid, I use `MediaQuery`, but for some reason the `gridView` is displayed differently on different devices, using which parameter in `gridDelegate:` can I fix this?
my `gridView` code:

```
 Widget buildCatalog(List<Product> product) => CustomScrollView(
        controller: sController,
        slivers: [
          SliverGrid(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                // mainAxisExtent: ,
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 300,
                childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                    (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.3),
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10),
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(childCount: product.length,
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2, top: 5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      InkWell(
                        child: Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                          child: Image.network(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text(),
                      // Spacer(),
                      const SizedBox(height: 8),
                      Text(),
                      const SizedBox(height: 5),
                      buildButton(index, productItem.id),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
]
);
```

This is my grid on big displays:
[image]

and this on small displays:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was flutter_screenutil package